# Time Complexity of Regular Languages

Tags: regular-languages, time-complexity

I wonder how I can go about proving that if a language L is decidable in o(nlog(n)) then L must be regular.

I should probably mention that by "decidable" I mean "being decidable by single-tape deterministic turing machine".

Thanks and regards
Guillermo

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84040/14578

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a classical result of Kobayashi, [On the structure of one-tape nondeterministic Turing machine time hierarchy](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397585901653), Theorem 3.3 on page 188. The idea is to use crossing sequences: you show an upper bound $O(1)$ on the size of any crossing sequence, and then use an argument of Hennie, [One-tape off-line Turing machine computations](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995865903992), Theorem 2 on page 561, to conclude that the language accepted by the machine is regular.

Comment: Thank you Yuval. Somehow I knew the result but didn't know the original reference or proof.