# what is complexity of language {a | a = x^2 }

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

What is known complexity of language {a | a = x^2}, is it possible there exist deterministic Turing machine (one input tape and one work tape) that accept this language in linear time?

Comment: "linear time" - I'd bet a no. Regexps are linear time in input size, and they are utterly insufficient for this task. Even recognizing palindromes is quadratic, IIRC

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0310046, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84040/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/17975/755